# Fulltext indexses prefixes

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I have seen such construction:

```
СREATE FULLTEXT INDEX product_all_idx ON product(description(5), name(3));
```

As i know 5 and 3 are prefixes of description and name. What is the main target of prefixes in fulltext index if we should search the word all over the text and not full match between prefix and word?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to ask the author of the create statement what they intended, but the MySQL developers agree with your assessment and just ignore those prefixes for [fulltext indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-fulltext):

> FULLTEXT indexes are supported only for InnoDB and MyISAM tables and can include only CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT columns. Indexing always happens over the entire column; **column prefix indexing is not supported and any prefix length is ignored if specified.**